# Abstracting away localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I've been building a Angular2 Library that adds a layer of abstraction to localStorage and sessionStorage to add functionality like permission levels and nice-ities and whatnot. The issue I'm having is that I want to throw errors if other devs try to access localStorage or sessionStorage directly. To ensure the permissions and other things are being used correctly.

So to do this basically I want to copy the localStorage and sessionStorage references, and then override their functions like so:

```
  this.localStorageReference = Object.assign({}, localStorage);
  this.sessionStorageReference = Object.assign({}, sessionStorage);

  const err = "Use the StorageStrategy, not localStorage or sessionStorage.";
  Storage.prototype._setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;
  Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value)
  {
    throw Error(err);
  }

  Storage.prototype._getItem = Storage.prototype.getItem;
  Storage.prototype.getItem = function(key){
    throw Error(err);
  }
```

Which the overrides work great and throw the error, the issue is that the Object.assign doesn't seem to be copying what I need it to. Because when I try to use the reference I don't have any of the methods.

```
this.localStorageReference.setItem(key, obj);
```

results in:

```
TypeError: this.localStorageReference.setItem is not a function
```

Looking at the localStorage docs, I'm not seeing anything obvious. Any Ideas?

Comment: `setItem`, and other functions, may not be enumerable and cannot be copied via `Object.assign()`.

Comment: Should `this.localStorageReference.setItem(key, obj);` throw the `err`? How would devs use the abstraction?

Comment: Seems like a  bad idea. What if someone has other apps on same domain that use storage and they want to use your convenience library for *'super cool new feature"* but also cross connect to data from other apps they have

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `Object.keys(localStorage)`.
You'll note that you see none of the method names. Same deal with `for (let key in localStorage)`, or anything else you care to try.

Those functions are not enumerable, or are on the prototype and not on the instance. Either way, they don't appear in enumerated lookups of "own" keys.

```
const fakeStorage = ["clear", "setItem", "getItem", "removeItem", /*...*/]
  .map(method => [method, localStorage[method].bind(localStorage)])
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

Now I'm not enumerating through keys, but rather enumerating through known method names.
Also note that some implementations of `Storage` are built to be tamper-proof (read-only properties; throw errors if the method isn't on the right object; et cetera).

Which begs the question... why not just protect your own access, rather than mandating the destruction of everyone else's usage?